# How to use derived columns in same hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, subquery, bigdata, derived-column

Could you please help me below query.

Suppose there is table employee and columns A , B and Date column.

I have to load data  from table employee to another table emp with below transformation applied

Transformation in Employee table

1. Absolute value of column A  - (column name in emp wil be ABS_A)
2. Absolute value of column B -(column name in emp wil be ABS_B)
3. Find the `sum(ABS_A)` for a given Date column

4.Find the `sum(ABS_b)` for a given Date column

5. Find `sum(ABS_A)/sum(ABS_B)` - column name will be Average.

So the Final table emp will have below columns

1.A

2.B

3.ABS_A

4.ABS_B

5.Average

How to handle such derived column in hive?

I tried below query but now working. could anyone guide me.

```
insert overwrite into emp
select 
A,
B,
ABS(A) as ABS_A,
ABS(B) as ABS_B,
sum(ABS_A) OVER PARTION BY DATE AS sum_OF_A,
sum(ABS_B) OVER PARTTION BY DATE AS sum_of_b,
avg(sum_of_A,sum_of_b) over partition by date as average
from employee
```

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Tihis: "Find sum(ABS_A)/sum(ABS_B) " does not match to what is in your query. It is not clear what is average in your understanding. Please provide some data example and expected output

Comment: Apart your issues with derived columns, average calculation seems wrong, It should not be (partition by date) because sum_of_A and sum_of_B are already calculated on the same partition(suppose it works), in other words, each date group already has the same sum_OF_A and sum_OF_B. So, please clarify what output do you expect and also the date column does not exist in the final output, this looks strange because sum are calculated for date partition. And without date in final output, you will get just duplicated sums for the whole date group. Better provide data input and desired output examples

Comment: thanks for your responses

@leftjoin: I've attached the table screenshot to the question.
The "expected output" should be like in the "Emp Table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive does not support using derived columns in the same subquery level. Use subqueries or functions in place of column aliases.

```
insert overwrite table emp 
select A, B, ABS_A, ABS_B, sum_OF_A, sum_of_b, `date`, sum_OF_A/sum_of_b as average
from      
(
select A, B, ABS(A) as ABS_A, ABS(B) as ABS_B, `date`,
       sum(ABS(A)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE) AS sum_OF_A, 
       sum(ABS(B)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE) AS sum_of_b
  from employee
)s;
```

Comment: Thanks @leftjoin - In final output table "Emp", the following two columns "sum_OF_A, sum_of_b" are not required. Then, do we need a temp table to calculate the average?

==="Also I've update the screenshot with formula".

Comment: @smp97 You mean subquery? No of couse you can do `sum(ABS(A)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE)/sum(ABS(B)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE)` . I just explained the technics available

Comment: @smp97 sum_OF_A is already sum in date partition. sum_OF_A=C11+C12, all you need is to divide

Comment: How to handle division by 0 in this scenario. Can I use as below
sum(ABS(A)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE)/ NULLIF (sum(ABS(B)) OVER (PARTTION BY DATE)). Could you guide.

Comment: @smp97 use case statements like this `case when sum_of_b > 0 then sum_OF_A/sum_of_b else .... end as average `